# How can I union or combine some columns and not others using sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have the following separate reports that I have a request to combine:

```
--REPORT #1
select o.orderid, o.orderdate, o.shippeddate, od.itemcode, od.itemdescription, od.quantity from orders o
join orderdetails od on od.orderid=o.orderid
where o.orderdate between '01-OCT-2017' and '01-NOV-2017' 
and o.shippeddate  between '01-NOV-2017' and '17-NOV-2017' 
and o.warehouseid=1 
and o.ordertypeid not in (7,8)
and o.orderstatusid in (7,8,9)

--REPORT #2
select o.orderid, o.orderdate, o.shippeddate, od.itemcode, od.itemdescription, od.quantity from orders o
join orderdetails od on od.orderid=o.orderid
where o.orderdate between '01-OCT-2017' and '01-NOV-2017' 
and o.shippeddate  between '01-OCT-2017' and '01-NOV-2017' 
and o.warehouseid=1 
and o.ordertypeid not in (7,8)
and o.orderstatusid in (7,8,9)

--REPORT #3
select o.orderid, o.orderdate, o.shippeddate, od.itemcode, od.itemdescription, od.quantity from orders o
join orderdetails od on od.orderid=o.orderid
where o.orderdate between '01-OCT-2017' and '01-NOV-2017'
and o.shippeddate >='01-NOV-2017'  
and o.warehouseid=1 
and o.ordertypeid not in (7,8)
and o.orderstatusid in (7,8,9)

--REPORT #4
select o.orderid, o.orderdate, o.shippeddate, od.itemcode, od.itemdescription, od.quantity from orders o
join orderdetails od on od.orderid=o.orderid
where o.orderdate between '01-OCT-2017' and '01-NOV-2017' 
and o.shippeddate is null
and o.warehouseid=1 
and o.ordertypeid not in (7,8)
and o.orderstatusid in (7,8,9)
```

I need to combine these reports so they can be run as one query. The issue I am running into is that the quantity column needs to be separate for each of the reports and using UNION combines them. Each separate Report may not have any results in common so a join doesn't work. So the end result would be something like:

orderid, orderdate, shippeddate, itemcode, itemdescription, QuanitityA, QuantityB, QuantityC, QuantityD

Comment: Despite your statements, there are common rows. If order date is in october and it is shipped on nov 1, that row will appear in the first three reports. Reports 1 and 3 will certainly have duplicates. Is it by chance that you don't see this?

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't `OR` do what you want?

```
select o.orderid, o.orderdate, o.shippeddate, od.itemcode,
       od.itemdescription, od.quantity
from orders o join
     orderdetails od 
     on od.orderid = o.orderid
where o.orderdate between '01-OCT-2017' and '01-NOV-2017' and
      (o.shippeddate between '01-NOV-2017' and '17-NOV-2017' or 
       o.shippeddate between '01-OCT-2017' and '01-NOV-2017' or
       o.shippeddate >= '01-NOV-2017' or
       o.shippeddate is null
      ) and
      o.warehouseid = 1 and
      o.ordertypeid not in (7, 8) and
      o.orderstatusid in (7, 8, 9);
```

Assuming `shippeddate` is always greater than `orderdate` (or `NULL`), then you can remove those conditions.  I would also advise using standard date formats:

```
select o.orderid, o.orderdate, o.shippeddate, od.itemcode,
       od.itemdescription, od.quantity
from orders o join
     orderdetails od 
     on od.orderid = o.orderid
where o.orderdate between '2017-10-01' and '2017-11-01' and
      ) and
      o.warehouseid = 1 and
      o.ordertypeid not in (7, 8) and
      o.orderstatusid in (7, 8, 9);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do a select distint with the common columns (orderid, orderdate, shippeddate, itemcode, itemdescription) and then start doing left join with each one of your queries.

Answer (score 0):

```
IS this what you want?
    select o.orderid
    , o.orderdate
    , o.shippeddate
    , od.itemcode
    , od.itemdescription
    , od.quantity AS QuantityA
    , NULL AS QuantityB
    , NULL AS QuantityC
    , NULL AS QuantityD
    from orders o
    join orderdetails od on od.orderid=o.orderid
    where o.orderdate between '01-OCT-2017' and '01-NOV-2017' 
    and o.shippeddate  between '01-NOV-2017' and '17-NOV-2017' 
    and o.warehouseid=1 
    and o.ordertypeid not in (7,8)
    and o.orderstatusid in (7,8,9)
    UNION
    select o.orderid
    , o.orderdate
    , o.shippeddate
    , od.itemcode
    , od.itemdescription
    , NULL AS QuantityA
    , od.quantity AS QuantityB
    , NULL AS QuantityC
    , NULL AS QuantityD 
    from orders o
    join orderdetails od on od.orderid=o.orderid
    where o.orderdate between '01-OCT-2017' and '01-NOV-2017' 
    and o.shippeddate  between '01-OCT-2017' and '01-NOV-2017' 
    and o.warehouseid=1 
    and o.ordertypeid not in (7,8)
    and o.orderstatusid in (7,8,9)
    UNION
    select o.orderid
    , o.orderdate
    , o.shippeddate
    , od.itemcode
    , od.itemdescription
    , NULL AS QuantityA
    , NULL AS QuantityB
    , od.quantity AS QuantityC
    , NULL AS QuantityD
    from orders o
    join orderdetails od on od.orderid=o.orderid
    where o.orderdate between '01-OCT-2017' and '01-NOV-2017'
    and o.shippeddate >='01-NOV-2017'  
    and o.warehouseid=1 
    and o.ordertypeid not in (7,8)
    and o.orderstatusid in (7,8,9)
    UNION
    select o.orderid
    , o.orderdate
    , o.shippeddate
    , od.itemcode
    , od.itemdescription
    , NULL AS QuantityA
    , NULL AS QuantityB
    , NULL AS QuantityC
    , od.quantity AS QuantityD
    from orders o
    join orderdetails od on od.orderid=o.orderid
    where o.orderdate between '01-OCT-2017' and '01-NOV-2017' 
    and o.shippeddate is null
    and o.warehouseid=1 
    and o.ordertypeid not in (7,8)
    and o.orderstatusid in (7,8,9)
```